# Extract all images from DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I to extract the `scr` value for all `img` tags within an HTML DOM  using Javascript?

```
<img src='this_value'>
```

Comment: i searched and forund the php version, for javascript, nothing;  foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
 {

    $image = $e->src;
 
 if(console)console.log();

    }

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work in all major browsers (e.g., IE8+). For more info on `querySelectorAll()` and a compatibility table have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll( 'img' );
var src = [];
for( var i = imgs.length; i--; ) {
  src.push( imgs[i].src );
}
```

**EDIT**

An alternative as suggested in the comments by @RobG and @KernelJames with better browser support:

```
var imgs = document.images;
var src = [];
for( var i = imgs.length; i--; ) {
  src.push( imgs[i].src );
}
```

Comment: You might want to note which browsers `querySelectorAll` works in.

Comment: The qSA line can be replaced with `var imgs = document.images`, which is supported by every browser in use (and most that aren't).

Comment: Just replace `document.querySelectorAll` with `document.images`

Answer (score 1):

using jquery:

```
var paths = []
$('img').each(function() {
  paths.push(this.src);
});
console.log(paths);
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: nobody, but does that matter? if so, feel free to downvote, i really don't care :) P.S. instead of correcting/downvoting everybody, why don't you just answer it correctly?

Comment: no jquery, just clean javascriut; thx anyway, it will be usefull at some point

Comment: @schaermu exactly,keep helping others ,i wote u a upwote :)...bcoz any hint can be useful

Comment: not downvoting, but this does not work for img that are nested in other tags, like `a`.  you may want to expand on this logic.